# Percentage of times we randomly take a set of items that is in a predefined set

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a bag with 100 balls in it, each ball has a number written on its surface and those numbers are not repeated (we can assume they go from 1 to 100, included). We also have a set of previously specified numbers $n=[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]$. If we randomly take five balls from the bag ($m=[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5]$), what is the percentage of numbers from $m$ that are in $n$, on average? i.e. if we randomly take $m$ in such a way that $(m1,m2,m3)\in n$, it shares 3/5 numbers.

Comment: The word *probability* does not mean the same thing as the word *odds*.  If you want probabilities, then use that word and only that word.  If you want odds, then use *that* and only that...  Don't mix them.

Comment: Now... as for your question... it is hard to tell what you mean by "a resulting value of 3/5" here... it seems as though you are counting partial successes.  Regardless, however you eventually rigorously define the problem, the final result will surely be a trivial textbook application of a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comments. I edited the question and tried to make it more understandable :)

Comment: Asking for the average proportion that match is a different question, but still follows immediately from introductory knowledge of hypergeometric distributions.  See in particular the "expected value" or "mean" section of the already linked wiki page.